# std::functions and lambda function passing

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function

I have a class that takes a `std::function` as a parameter which I assign a lambda function. It works in the constructor but it stops working after that. The debugger says `f` is "empty" after running the first line. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<void(std::string)> const& fn;

class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass(fn _f) : f(_f) { F(); }
    void F() { f("hello"); };

private:
    fn f;
};


int main()
{
    TestClass t([](std::string str) {std::cout << str << std::endl; });

    t.F();

    return 0;
}
```

Calling `t.F()` causes a fault. Why?

I can solve it by changing it to the following:

```
int main()
{
    fn __f = [](std::string str) {std::cout << str << std::endl; };
    TestClass t(__f);

    t.F();

    return 0;
}
```

but again, this does not work when I change `fn` to `auto`!

```
int main()
{
    auto __f = [](std::string str) {std::cout << str << std::endl; };
    TestClass t(__f);

    t.F();

    return 0;
}
```

What is the explanation of why this is happening?

Comment: You bind a reference to a local variable, which is destroyed soon thereafter, leaving the reference dangling. Any use of `f` afterwards exhibits undefined behavior. The class member should be of type `std::function<...>`, not `std::function<...>&`.

Comment: Please avoid prefixing names with underscores.  double underscore names are reserved for the implementation and in certain places.cases so are single underscores.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This does not explain why the last code with `auto` does not wotk

Comment: I see the local variable.
But, what about the third case? Why does it also crash there? The variable is not local.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 Does too. It's the same reason. `__f` is a lambda. When it's passed to `TestClass` constructor, a temporary `std::function` is constructed, and destroyed at the semicolon.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It should be copied into `f` member, shouldn't it?

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 `f` is a reference. Nothing can be copied to it, only bound to it. In this case, what's bound to it is a temporary that's destroyed soon thereafter.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oops, misread it. So, the answer to this question is "remove the '&' sign from the typedef".

Comment: don' hide a reference (or a pointer) type in a typedef.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that (1) `fn` is defined as **reference** (to const); (2) lambda and `std::function` are not the same type; (3) You can't bind reference to object with different type directly.

For the 1st case,

```
TestClass t([](std::string str) {std::cout << str << std::endl; });
t.F();
```

A temporary lambda is created and then converted to `std::function` which is a temporary too. The temporary `std::function` is bound to the parameter `_f` of the constructor and bound to member `f`. The temporary will be destroyed after this statement, then `f` becomes dangled, when `t.F();` it fails.

For the 2nd case,

```
fn __f = [](std::string str) {std::cout << str << std::endl; };
TestClass t(__f);
t.F();
```

A temporary lambda is created and then bound to reference (to const). Then its lifetime is extended to the lifetime of the reference `__f`, so the code is fine.

For the 3rd case,

```
auto __f = [](std::string str) {std::cout << str << std::endl; };
TestClass t(__f);
t.F();
```

lambda is created and then converted to `std::function` which is a temporary. The temporary `std::function` is bound to the parameter `_f` of the constructor and bound to member `f`. The temporary will be destroyed after this statement, then `f` becomes dangled, when `t.F();` it fails.

---

<sup>(1) You could declare `fn` as non-reference like `typedef std::function<void(std::string)> fn;`, then `std::function` will be copied and every case would work well.

(2) Don't use names begin with double underscore, they're reserved in C++.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

```
typedef std::function<void(std::string)> const& fn;
```

This isn't a `std::function`, it is a reference to a `std::function`.

```
TestClass(fn _f) : f(_f) { F(); }
fn f;
```

Here you take a `const&` to a `std::function` and bind it to another `const&` to a `std::function`.  The `F()` in the body of the constructor works, as the reference is valid at least as long as the constructor is.

```
TestClass t([](std::string str) {std::cout << str << std::endl; });
```

This creates a `std::function` temporary created from the lambda.  This temporary lasts as long as the current line (until the `;`).

Then the temporary `std::function` is discarded.

As `TestClass` takes the `std::function` by `const&`, it doesn't extend the temporaries lifetime.

So after the line, any call of the `std::function const&` is undefined behavior, which you see in the call to `.F()` later.

```
fn __f = [](std::string str) {std::cout << str << std::endl; };
```

This does reference lifetime extending.  The temporary `std::function` created from the lambda has its lifetime extended to the lifetime of the `__f` variable.

As an aside, this line also makes your program ill formed, no diagnostic required, by having a variable containing a double underscore.  Such identifiers are reserved for the implementation of the compiler, you may not create them.

```
TestClass t(__f);
```

We then pass this reference (referring to a lifetime extended temporary), and everything works.

```
auto __f = [](std::string str) {std::cout << str << std::endl; };
```

This creates a variable `__f` (see above, bad name) that is a lambda.

A lambda is not a `std::function`.  A `std::function` can be created from a lambda implicitly.

```
TestClass t(__f);
```

This creates a temporary `std::function` from the lambda, passes it to the `TestClass` constructor, then destroys the temporary.

After this line, the call to `.F()` ends up following a dangling reference, and undefined behavior results.

Your core problem may be that you think a lambda is a `std::function`.  It is not.  A `std::function` can store a lambda.

Your second problem is typedefing something as a `const&`, which is almost always a really stupid idea.  References behave differently than values in fundamental ways.

Your third problem is the double understore in your variable names.  (Or an identifier starting with an `_` followed by a capital letter).

If you want to know how `std::function` works and what it is, there are plenty of good SO posts on the subject with various levels of technical detail.